# Change text of Ajax post return

Tags: php, ajax

I have a loop:

```
do {
// show items
<input type="hidden" id="contestant_id" value="'.$row_contestants['contestant_id'].'">
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="'.$userinfo['user_id'].'">
<button class="vote" onclick="vote()">vote</button>
<div id="result"></div>
} while ($row....);
```

And my function:

```
function vote () {
var val1 = $('#contestant_id').val();
var val2 = $('#user_id').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"vote.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: { contestant_id: val1, user_id: val2 },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
    }
 });
```

}

What I want to do is have the "vote" text from here:

```
<button class="vote" onclick="vote()">vote</button>
```

change to something else like "voted!" when I get the response. I sort of had it but of course it's showing here:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

And it's only showing under the 1st result of my loop.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: Add some increment value to each Id to make Ids unique like id="contestant_id_(some unique value)"

Comment: I added that but now I'm all messed up in how to get them as variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this from html to function and handle in the script

```
<button class="vote" onclick="vote(this)">vote</button>

function vote (el) {
var val1 = $('#contestant_id').val();
var val2 = $('#user_id').val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"vote.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: { contestant_id: val1, user_id: val2 },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
        if (response  == 'Yes') {
           var text = el.text();
           var values = text.split(' ');
           var count = 1;
           if (values.length == 2) { 
             count = values[1].parseInt + 1;
           }
           el.text('Voted ' + count);
        }
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: That makes more sense. But in my vote.php file I do a mysql insert and do if "yes" else "no". How else can I send a success response?

Comment: Add one if condition . Updated my answer. but no sure how you are sending response.

Comment: I changed yours to $('.vote').html(response) because it's in the .vote class, not #result. It works but what if I add an increment number to .vote?

Comment: the same you are adding . You can get text and increment it . Updated it

Comment: I just updated my answer for your idea. You can play with that based on your needs

Comment: I just checked but I don't see it adding an increment number to the .vote class. It's still returning the response on all the buttons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118057/discussion-between-ironank-and-vijaykumar).